# MongoDB - Find duplicated elements in record property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm struggling to identified duplicated elements in my MongoDB records, here is my problem :

I have a Mongo collection named "elements".

Example of a record in this collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c824b6"),
    "name" : "A",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d7"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82534")
        }, 
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d6"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82533")
        }, 
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d8"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82532")
        }, 
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b3048e851271e80c826a5")
        }, 
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b3048e851271e80c826ad")
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to identify records where the array "items" contains objects with the same "ref_id".

In my example we can see that the last two objects of the "items" array have the same "ref_id" : **ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d5")**.

I tried a bunch of aggregate function but unfortunately couldn't came out with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.elements.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$items"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "root":{
                $first:"$$ROOT"
            },
            "items":{
                $push:"$items"
            },
            "distinctItems":{
                $addToSet: "$items.ref_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $ne:[
                    {
                        $size:"$items"
                    },
                    {
                        $size:"$distinctItems"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "root.items":"$items"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":"$root"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c824b6"),
    "name" : "A",
    "items" : [
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d7"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82534")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d6"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82533")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d8"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82532")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b3048e851271e80c826a5")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b3048e851271e80c826ad")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d654b9d7d0ab652c42315f2"),
    "name" : "B",
    "items" : [
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d7"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82534")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d6"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82533")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d8"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82532")
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c824b6"),
    "name" : "A",
    "items" : [
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d7"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82534")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d6"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82533")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d8"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2205e851271e80c82532")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b3048e851271e80c826a5")
        },
        {
            "ref_id" : ObjectId("5d1b2204e851271e80c823d5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1b3048e851271e80c826ad")
        }
    ]
}
```

**Explanation:** We are populating an array of distinct `ref_id` from each document and matching if the size of the populated array is equal to the size of actual `items` array.